# Backwards compatible replacement for C# 8.0's async streams

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, mono

I hope the question title does not become imprecise, but it may happen that a direct replacement isn't available and a code restructuring becomes inevitable.

My task is to stream audio frames from HTTP, pipe them through ffmpeg and then shove them into some audio buffer.
Now a classical approach would probably involve multiple threads and lots of garbage collection I want to avoid.

My modern attempt was using `async IAsyncEnumerable<Memory<byte>>`, where I'd basically read content from HTTP into a fixed-size byte array, that is allocated once.
Then I'd `yield return` the Memory struct ("pointer"), which would cause the caller to immediately consume and transform that content via ffmpeg.

With that, I'd stay in lock-step defined by the chunk reads from the HttpClient. That way, the whole processing would happen on one thread and I would only have one big byte array as data store with a long lifetime.

The problem with this is, that Unity's Mono Version doesn't support the C# 8.0 feature of async streams (i.e. awaiting the async enumerable). So I need to come up with a replacement.

I thought about using System.Threading.Channels, but those already have a few caveats in the way the control flow is handled: With Channels, I cannot guarantee that the written `Memory<T>` is immediately read. As such it can happen that http is overwriting the backing buffer before the other end has read content. This would mean copying lots of data, causing garbage.

An oldschool alternative would be to maintain some kind of ring buffer, where I have a write and a read pointer that is moved whenever each end reads/writes. hand-rolling that felt dumb though, maybe there is a roughly equivalent and elegant API?

Also would you rather just have two Threads and have them busy wait? Or can I maybe just accept the garbage collector pressure and use some regular queue structure, that potentially even uses notify/wait to wake up waiting threads, so they don't have to SpinWait/busy wait?

Comment: I think you're going to have a real tough time reproducing a feature in a lower version of the language, as what you're trying to replicate needs actual compiler support to pull off. This does sound like an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I think you could replicate it with a `while` loop and `await ReadAsync`, some actual code would help us

Comment: Have you looked at the [AsyncEnumerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator) package?